# How to use specified value when indexing operation fails (e.g. b[x][y])?

Tags: python, python-2.7

If there is no results from the mysql query.. 
how to set a variable to '0'

is the question.

```
import _mysql

def db():
    a = _mysql.connect('localhost','1','','a')
    return a

b=db()

b.query('select id from people where id=' + a + ' limit 1')
d = b.store_result()
b = d.fetch_row(0)
b = b[0][0]
```

if the mysql has no result .. then this script will error due to

```
b = b[0][0]
```

i need to set "b" to "0" if there is no such thing as b[0][0]

because when something is not found via mysql.. then i get this error

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

**UPDATE**

looking for a "try" alternative. i do not understand the word "try" if i want to simply use the logic of "if does not exist" rather than "touch it and try it to see what happens first"

**UPDATE 2**

would be awesome if someone can show me the

```
a = locals().get('a', '0')
```

version of this.

**UPDATE 3**

perhaps i should run count(*) so mysql can give me "0"
that i am looking for. and then decide if i should go back into mysql with another query or not.

Comment: Use a try/except block?

Comment: try/except does not fit in my logic ... the term "try" says "try".. i do not want to "try" anything. i want to set it to "0" if it does not exist.

Comment: I don't know much about python, but can't you just check the length of the array?

Comment: Assuming that it is known *which* operation fails (and for example following I propose that `b[0]` is the source of the error), consider: `result = row[0][0] if row else 0`. This sort of if guard has to be repeated for every case (i.e. what if `row[0]` was not indexable?)

Comment: b = len(b[0][0]) ? and then .. if b > 2 ?.. due to 2 parenthesis ?

Comment: well if there is no such record.. i suppose the whole operation is failing but why must go look for b[0] ?

Comment: does anyone have this version of it : b=locals().get('b[0][0]', '0') i dont know if that will work because might not be a "local"

Comment: It looks like you need to learn about try/except then. This is a very important part of the python language.

Comment: Why use `_mysql` instead of one of the pep 249 compliant wrappers?  e.g. `MySQLdb`?

Comment: the very word "wrapper" suggests.. "something has been wrapped up".. in other words core is no longer direct and thus things become "slow"

Comment: A "try" statement is the simple and pythonic way to do this. I think you're making this problem harder than it needs to be.

Comment: for example. suppose a star wants to vanish to complete void.. will it first have to "try" void ?.. void can not be tried because it is not there. if so why are we "try" ing in this python statement to see if b[0][0] exists or not ?

Comment: I'm glad you brought up God. I'm sure he'd agree that "it's better to ask forgiveness than permission" which is what you're doing with a try statement.

Comment: But it *can* be tried. It either succeeds, in which case the value is assigned from `b[0][0]`, or it fails, in which case you can handle the exception by assigning your own value, `0`.

Comment: perhaps the logic here in python is " try to see if b can equate to b[0][0] ".. even this logic is flaw. that is not what i am looking for.. i am looking to see if "b[0][0]" is void or full.

Comment: i have not yet tried "len(b[0][0])" but perhaps if that works.. that would be as close to GOD as possible.

Comment: ultimately i simply changed the mysql query to count(*) now it throws out "0" value as well. python ruined us

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> import _mysql
>
> def db():
>     a = _mysql.connect('localhost','1','','a')
>     return a
>
> b=db()
>
> b.query('select id from people where id=' + a + ' limit 1')
> d = b.store_result()
> b = d.fetch_row(0)
>
> # if any error happens then set b = 0
> # ie. there is no b[0][0]
> try: 
>     b = b[0][0]
> except Exception as e:
>     b = 0
> ```

Comment: exactly this, this is exactly what try/except is for.

Comment: Why the broad except?  I'm guessing that `b` will be `None` which isn't indexible -- so you should get a `TypeError` or possibly an `IndexError` but those are the only 2 options that I can see. . .

Comment: Pretty sad that this correct answer will never be accepted because it doesn't fit in with the OP's bizarre ideas about God and black holes.

Comment: the answer says "try to see if b can equate to b[0][0] and if there is an error..  forgive the error and set the b to 0".. this answer is disturbing. all i want is a code that says.. "if b[0][0] is void then set b to 0" simple and basic. to the point. inline with logic and cosmos.

Comment: Think of it this way... do you take the batteries out of your remote control and test them for charge every time you want to turn on your TV? Or do you just try to turn on your TV, and only get new batteries if there is an "error" (flat battery). Is that against logic and the cosmos?

Comment: forget batteries and imagine floating in the cosmos. you either exist or you do not exist. in other words.. b[0][0] either exists or it does not exist.

Comment: OK. I give up. For what it's worth, in other programming languages your philosophy would probably makes more sense, as exceptions are generally regarded as "exceptional" circumstances that "shouldn't happen" in the normal running of the program. Python programmers don't tend to use them that way. They are (usually) more than happy to use a try/catch statement to solve the kind of problem you have. Likewise they would just "try" to open a file rather than checking that it exists, and is not locked, and has read permission etc.

Comment: it is a violation against the laws of cosmos . the big bang theory.. it says nothing existed once upon a time. in other words something is either void or not void.

Comment: If you find it a violation of the laws of the cosmos, I suggest you find another programming language, because Python will not make you happy. Golang or VB6 might suit you better.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an aversion to try/except blocks you can carefully check the indices are in range before trying to access them.

```
if b and b[0]:
    b = b[0][0]
else:
    b = 0
```

or succinctly

```
b = b[0][0] if b and b[0] else 0
```

This checks that `b` is not `None` and not empty, and that `b[0]` is not `None` and not empty, so you can get `b[0][0]` without an exception (unless they might turn out to be not lists or tuples, in which case, really, just use a try/except block).

As for your other question, about `locals().get('b[0][0]',0)`, `locals()` can get you a variable from its name, but the local variable's name would be `b`, not `b[0][0]`, so `locals()` is not going to help you.

Comment: do you happen to know the `b=locals().get('b[0][0]', '0')` version of it ?

Comment: `locals().get('b[0][0]',0)` will not work because `b[0][0]` is not the name of a variable. It's an operation on the variable `b`.